# Fieldnode Positioning (swift)

Tags: xcode, swift, position, field, sprite-kit

Im implementing a SKfieldnode in my game but im not sure if my code is wrong or a bug in the 
sprite kit engine. when i use the code the game freezes and a bit later all the nodes that were in its radius disappeared.

I wanted to used the following code:

```
var field = SKFieldNode.vortexField()
       field.exclusive = true
           field.enabled = true
       field.minimumRadius = 50
            field.region = SKRegion(radius: 200)
            field.strength = 0.001
            field.position = CGPoint(x:CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), y:CGRectGetMidY(self.frame)+100)
        self.addChild(field)
```

and figured out that removing the +100 at the positioning the problem fixed but i don't want it there >:-(

thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found what caused this problem, looks like you can not spawn a node on the exact same position as the field so adding a +1 to the x fixed it